# How to obtain aspect ratio from .avi file in c#

Tags: c#, winforms, video, directshow, aspect-ratio

I have been provided with a .avi movie and i have to display it using DirectShow lib. So i am using a pictureBox to display bitmap image frame by frame but I want to maintain Aspect Ratio. How to do this in  Windows Form. Thanks in advance.
**Edit**: I have to store some of the bitmap images in the same Aspect Ratio.

Comment: **PictureBox does it** for you. You may display image centered (eventually cropped) or zoomed (keeping aspect ratio).

Comment: if you are using DS why are you displaying bitmaps instead of running the video?

Comment: Actually, I have work with frames of the movie also.

Comment: when you get the bitmap from DS, it wont have changed the AR, so it should be in the original AR

Comment: in the format: md.WriteBitmapBits( frameNumber/ frameRate, length, width, FileName+".bmp"); We have to enter the dimensions.

Comment: Is there a function that creates images without taking dimensions as parameters

Comment: Use SampleGrabber filter to capture individual frames

Comment: You can use [IBasicVideo2::GetPreferredAspectRatio](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd389551(v=vs.85).aspx) or [IVMRWindowlessControl9::GetNativeVideo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd390544(v=vs.85).aspx).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AVI format does not hold aspect ratio for video, so you can only assume square pixels and aspect ratio based on pixel resolution of the video stream. Most of the ways to obtain specific frame/bitmap out of the stream get you image in original video resolution. Your further manipulation with the bitmap trying to preserve the aspect ration assumes that you do simple math with the image dimensions: you scale the control or area you draw the image to appropriately: original-width * presentation-height = original-height * presentation-width. Or simply leverage - if applicable - WinForms control's ability to keep aspect ratio.

When you present video using DirectShow API (video renderers), there is an option to keep aspect ratio right there, however it slightly differs depending on the version of the renderer you are using.

Comment: Is height of the video same as resolution height...or to be precise is ratio of height to width of the video same as resoluton height to resolution width.

Comment: In AVI files - yes, because descriptor simply has no fields to override the ratio. Other containers might be more flexible and have pixel resolution and also separate aspect ratio. This way it is possible to define so called "non-square pixels" and effective aspect ratio adjustment.

Comment: in case of mpg format is the pixels "non-square"?.. like i have to use avi as well as mpg videos. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: MPEG streams **might** have aspect ratio information and hence define non-square pixels. It does not means that those files do always have aspect ratio vs. pixel resolution mismatch.